# Visualforce replacement for ConvertedLeadView page

Tags: lead-conversion

I have a trigger that automates the conversion of a Lead based on some criteria, and after the Lead gets saved (and converted) it redirects me to a page that gives information about the Lead's related records via the conversion.

[image: ConvertedLeadView]

- (Store & Contact is a custom label for Account)

The URL for this is: https://cs14.salesforce.com/p/lead/ViewConvertedLead/d?id=00Qc0000004eOD5

I'm wondering if there is a way to override this view with a VF page that I can automate a redirect to the Account. Failing that, I suppose it is possible to leverage JavaScript in the side panel to manipulate the URL to a separate VF page (which I'd prefer not to do).

Comment: javascript side panel no longer available as an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override that view, but you can create a URL button called "Convert Lead" which loads a simple Visualforce page, calls your custom conversion logic behind the scenes, and forwards to the resulting page.

In essence this is moving your logic from being called in a trigger to being called from a Controller.